# add guid on a ROME rss file

Tags: java, rss, rome

I am creating an rss feed in Java using ROME, but for the life of me, i can find how a GUID on it.

```
public boolean addRss(String msg,String msgLink,Date date){
        List<SyndEntry> entries = new ArrayList<SyndEntry>();
        SyndEntry entry; 
        entry = new SyndEntryImpl();
        entry.setTitle(msg);
        if(msgLink!=null){
            entry.setLink(msgLink);
        }       
        entry.setPublishedDate(date);
         entries.add(entry);
         feed.setEntries(entries);

        return true;
    }
```

This code works for creating a rss item. the problem is that i need to add a timestamp as a GUID. So i tried to use a Guid object as so

```
Guid g=new Guid();
g.setValue(date.toString());
g.setPermaLink(false);
```

But I cant find a way to add this to my item, for example there is no `entry.setGuid(Guid)`

**Edit**
It turns out that `Guid()` can be added to an `Item()` not a `SyndFeedImpl()` as i have in my case, and i cant find a way to add an Item to my SyndFeedImpl. I would rather have some way of adding a guid to a SyndFeedImpl() than re writing the whole thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SyndFeed.setURI](https://github.com/rometools/rome/blob/master/rome/src/main/java/com/rometools/rome/feed/synd/SyndFeed.java#L168) sets the unique identifier. Depending on the type of feed you are creating (atom/rss) the resulting xml will be different, but anyway the identifier will be there:

```
SyndEntry entry = new SyndEntryImpl();
entry.setTitle("entry title 1");
entry.setUri("http://localhost/feed/item1GUID");
entry.setLink("http://localhost/feed/item1");
```

result as rss 2.0:

```
<item>
<title>entry title 1</title>
<link>http://localhost/feed/item1</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://localhost/feed/item1GUID</guid>
</item>
```

same entry as atom 1.0:

```
<entry>
<title>entry title 1</title>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://localhost/feed/item1" />
<author>
<name />
</author>
<id>http://localhost/feed/item1GUID</id>
</entry>
```

Comment: That did it! thanks! i just used a date instead of a url, just to make it unique. like so `entry.setUri(new Date().toString());` thanks again

Comment: This is not very well described in the docs, and the same is true for getting the GUID via `entry.getUri()`. I also ran into trouble since I tried entryInfo.getUri() which ends up implementing [something totally different](https://github.com/rometools/rome/blob/master/rome-modules/src/main/java/com/rometools/modules/itunes/AbstractITunesObject.java#L72).  (`entryInfo` being one of [these](https://github.com/rometools/rome/blob/master/rome-modules/src/main/java/com/rometools/modules/itunes/EntryInformationImpl.java))